# MEL : extract entire value of a keyframe in maya

Tags: maya, keyframe, mel

My question is pretty simple, i use a mel command to extract camera data value.

i use this code :

```
keyframe -q -vc Camera0Node.translateX
```

it result : 2385.11

the problem is my keyframe value is 2385.11010742

the difference is minimal but i want to have the exact value

any idea how i can get non rounded value ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the result **is** your full value, but Maya only displays it as a rounded number.

As an example, let's assign that value directly to a variable:

`$val = 2385.11010742;`

Then print it to console:

`print($val);`

The result displays `2385.110107`.

Now let's do a comparison:

`print($val == 2385.110107); // returns 0 for False`

But when comparing to the original value:

`print($val == 2385.11010742); // returns 1 for True`